# How to format the first column in a Symfony Table the same as the first row?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

A [Symfony Table](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/table.html) normally colors the first row differently from the other rows. I would however like to have the first row AND the first column to have the same styling. I know there exists a `TableStyle` but I can not figure out how to give the first column + first row the same styling. In this example Table I would like the first column to also color green (the text Row A, Row B and Row C).

This example Table can be generated using the following code:

```
$table = new Table($output);
$table
    ->setHeaders(array('Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C'))
    ->setRows(array(
        array('Row A', 'Divine Comedy', 'Dante Alighieri'),
        array('Row B', 'A Tale of Two Cities', 'Charles Dickens'),
        array('Row C', 'The Lord of the Rings', 'J. R. R. Tolkien'),
    ))
;
$table->render();
```

[image: examplee]

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `TableStyle` instance and set `cellRowContentFormat` like this:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
$table = new Table($output);
$style = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\TableStyle();
$style->setCellRowContentFormat('<info> %s </info>');
$table->setColumnStyle(0, $style);
$table
    ->setHeaders(array('Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C'))
    ->setRows(array(
        array('Row A', 'Divine Comedy', 'Dante Alighieri'),
        array('Row B', 'A Tale of Two Cities', 'Charles Dickens'),
        array('Row C', 'The Lord of the Rings', 'J. R. R. Tolkien'),
    ))
;
$table->render();
```

You can take a look on `TableStyle::$cellRowContentFormat` and `TableStyle::$cellHeaderFormat` members default values: by default `$cellHeaderFormat` is `'<info>%s</info>'`, and this value makes cell header green (info color).